# Insert Variables In AT commandes

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm

I'am trying to apply USSD operation with variable codes, for example this piece of code return my account balance:

```
             gsm.SimpleWriteln("AT+CUSD=1,\"*100#\"");
```

i want to change "*100#" to variable so gsm.SimpleWrite uses what the variable contains. I want to find how to make it work like this:

```
             gsm.SimpleWriteln("AT+CUSD=1,\"Variable\"");
```

EDIT: here is my code to give you a better view. it return balance in serial monitor.

```
#include "SIM900.h"



  void setup() 
    {
   Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("GSM Shield testing.");
       if (gsm.begin(9600))
            Serial.println("\nstatus=READY");
      else Serial.println("\nstatus=IDLE");

         gsm.SimpleWriteln("AT+CUSD=1,\"*100#\"");
      delay(10000);
             char msg[200];
             gsm.read(msg, 200);
            Serial.print("resp: ");
            Serial.println(msg);
 }
    void loop()
     {

    }
```

Comment: What kind of variable? And what library has the SimpleWriteln method?

Comment: im using SIM900.h. for example var1 = *100# and var2 = *122# i want to applied it like that.

Comment: gsm.SimpleWriteln is different from serial.print in many ways, including syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot find which "SIM900.h" library you are using - none of the ones I found have "SimpleWriteln" in them, so this is pure assumption about what functions and overloads may be available.

Just split your string into chunks, like you would with any serial device:

```
gsm.SimpleWrite("AT+CUSD=1,\"");
gsm.SimpleWrite(command);
gsm.SimpleWriteln("\"");
```

Where `command` is a suitable container for your data - say `const char *`.

Comment: check the post i added the code, and i tried what u said, it returns error. Sim900.h lib located at: Arduino\libraries\SIM908IDE100. i think its with th  default libs.

Comment: You must have installed that library. That means you must have downloaded it from somewhere. That means you must surely know where you downloaded it from. Unless you can tell us that we can't help you further.

Comment: I think I have found a copy online, though I can't be sure. It looks like the library hasn't been well written - it doesn't support the F() macro (which is kind of stupid really). I shall remove those from my code example.

Comment: any other suggestions to make a USSD operation?

Comment: Does my example not do what you want?

Comment: it returns Error. which means wrong syntax in AT manuel

Comment: Did you mistakenly use SimpleWriteln instead of SimpleWrite ?

Comment: it worked! thank you. i just define command as char* , like this.  char *command